# My regex doesn't match with a certain input - java

Tags: java, regex, command-line, boolean

I use the following regex : "( ?([0-9]+)-?)+".

I try to look at if there's any minus character between two numbers. The regex should allow minuses before numbers but not between them.

I test it with the following command line input : "4 6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9", the program returns what it is expected to return (true to a boolean value).
Also, when the command line input is : "-4 6 8 2 5 -3 4 3 9", the program works and returns false to the boolean(expected). But, whenever I input : "4 -6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9", the program shows the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5-3"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Ex5.main(Ex5.java:32)
```

Which means my boolean is false, and I do not know why, because it should return true.

Comment: Adrien, just a hint, instead of put all your code in the question, limit your problem for a single slice of code. For example: Why the regex "( ?([0-9]+)-?)+" don't match with the input "4 -6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9"

Comment: Could you use `boolean hasMinuses = listString.contains("-")`? If so, this would save you debugging your regex.

Comment: Well no I cannot, I want to allow - but only when it's NOT after a number

Comment: and here you go, I changed my post

Comment: Looks like you do know why your boolean is false. Your regex does not catch your 5-3.
You could try a regex checker like https://regexr.com/

Comment: Post the code that does not work, explain what is wrong using your 4 example strings as samples and provide expected behavior for these 4 strings.

Comment: One guy tells me to post my code and the other tells me to take it off, I'm kind of confused as to what I have to do tbh. I showed my redex and the example strings, it should be enough, right ?

Comment: @AdrienAacha It is quite obscure now what you want. Please edit the question to explain what expected result for each of the provided strings is.

Comment: here, I changed it again it should be ok now

Comment: It is not OK. Provide a Java fiddle with the strings and expected behaviors. Please post the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at your [`( ?([0-9]+)-?)+` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrSDO0/1): only `4 6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9` line is matched as a whole line while `4 -6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9`, `-4 6 8 2 5 -3 4 3 9`, and `4 -6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9` are matched partially.

If you get *false*, it means you are using `.matches()` method. You may use

```
(?: ?-?([0-9]+))+
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mrSDO0/2).

To get the same functionality you currently have, and if you use it with `.matches()`, you will match all of your four strings provided above and Group 1 will contain the last chunk of digits captured (since the pattern contains a repeated capturing group, only the last number will get stored in `.group(1)`).

**Details**

- `^` (implied in `.matches()`) - start of string
- `(?: ?-?([0-9]+))+` - 1 or more occurrences of:

  - `?` - an optional space
  - `-?` - an optional `?`
  - `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `$` (implied in `.matches()`) - end of string

Comment: It works even worse than last time ! Now the boolean is true for whatever value I enter, even just "4 5 6 9" "8 63 3"

Comment: @AdrienAacha You have not explained a thing about how it should work. You only complained of 3 lines not being matched. I explained why and suggested a pattern that does.

Comment: I have explicitely said that it should return true to a boolean value if the minus sign is between two numbers but not when it is simply before a number

Comment: @AdrienAacha Then all you need [`[0-9]-[0-9]`](https://regex101.com/r/mrSDO0/3), right? To detect if there is a digit-hyphen-digit inside the string? See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/DjF7gg).

Comment: Or here is Attempt #2 - [`^[0-9]+(?:[-\s][0-9]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mrSDO0/4). See [**the Java demo**](https://ideone.com/Pt9KVv).

Comment: attempt number two returns false for "4 6 8 2 5-3 4 3 9" when it should be true

Comment: It returns true for "4 6 8 2 3-4 3 9" "4" and false for "4 6 -8 2 -4 3 9" "4" but I still get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3-2"" for "4 6 8 3-2 -4 3 9" "4"

Comment: @AdrienAacha No one can help you with that part since we do not know the code.

Comment: it gives an Exception because the value of the boolean is false when it should be true.

Comment: @AdrienAacha What are the exact strings? `String s = "\"4 6 8 2 3-4 3 9\" \"4\"";`? What are the *exact* requirements for the allowed pattern? If you are keeping that information to yourself, no one can help you. **Provide a Java fiddle** with the strings and expected behaviors.

Comment: @Adrien, how are you? Do you need more help with this? If yes, please provide a Java fiddle with exact strings and expected results.

Comment: no no it's alright i decided it'd be better if I didn't implement this regex after all, thanks for checking in

Answer (score 0):

You can try ***((\s)?\d+(-\d)?)+***
It will work for all cases. Please let me know if any case is failed.
For Java code, you can use ***((\s)?\d+(\-\d)?)+***